# AWS lambda instance shuts down while xstate invoke promise

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, xstate

I have a lambda function that uses xstate to perform certain tasks sequentially and one of the steps is to save data to dynamo db. But my lambda ends execution as soon as the below line is being executed.

```
const response = await new DynamoDB.DocumentClient().put(params).promise();
```

my code :

```
import {Handler} from "aws-lambda";
import {interpret} from 'xstate';
import { Machine} from "xstate";
import {PutItemInput} from "aws-sdk/clients/dynamodb";
import {DynamoDB} from "aws-sdk";

export const recordProcessor: Handler = async (event) => {
  console.log('records size----->', event.Records.length);
  for (const record of event.Records) {
      const body = JSON.parse(record.body);
      console.log('body ----->', body);

    interpret(Machine({id:'test',
      context:body,
      initial: 'start',
      states:{
        start: {
          invoke: {
            src: context => initiate(context),
            onDone: {
              target: 'success'
            }
          }
        },
        success: {
          type: 'final'
        }
      }
    })).onTransition(state => {
      if (state.changed) {
        console.log('state ----> ', state.value);
      }
    }).onDone(() => console.log('done--->')).start();
  }


  async function initiate(context: any) {
    console.log('DbDynamoImpl ::: insert ::: start :::');
    let params: PutItemInput = {
      TableName: 'test',
      Item: context
    };
    try {
      const response = await new DynamoDB.DocumentClient().put(params).promise();
      console.log('DbDynamoImpl ::: insert ::: response :::', response);
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("DynamoDb insert error", e);
      return false;
    }
  }

};
```

Comment: hard to say anything without looking at the complete code.

Comment: added test code as I cannot share my whole code.

Comment: I had to change implementation from xstate to chain of responsibility design pattern due to project timeline and haven't really got time to check by Greg and Iko. But will check as soon as get time and update... Others also free to upvote if it works.

Answer (score 0):

you are resolving Promise before hitting `return` statement. Can you try to `resolve` `Promise` with values that you need to return? Then it will go to onDone block with those values. Also having `try` and `catch` block over here is redundant as `service` in `xstate` will automatically handle that for you.

Just return the promise in service invoke statement, because it is needs to be a function that return a `Promise`

```js
function initiate(context: any) {
  console.log('DbDynamoImpl ::: insert ::: start :::');
  let params: PutItemInput = {
    TableName: 'test',
    Item: context,
  };
  return new DynamoDB.DocumentClient().put(params).promise();
}
```

Then in your `onDone` block you can `console.log('DbDynamoImpl ::: insert ::: response :::', response);`

```js
onDone: {
  target: 'success',
  actions: (ctx, e) => console.log('DbDynamoImpl ::: insert ::: response :::', e),
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the machine interpret, and interactions into a promise allows you to wait for the state machine to hit a final state.

Something roughly like this

```
export const recordProcessor: Handler = async (event) => {
  console.log('records size----->', event.Records.length);
  for (const record of event.Records) {
      const body = JSON.parse(record.body);
      console.log('body ----->', body);
      await setupMachine(...);
...
}

function setupMachine(...){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    interpret(Machine({id:'test',
      context:body,
      initial: 'start',
      states:{
        start: {
          invoke: {
            src: context => initiate(context),
            onDone: {
              target: 'success'
            }
          }
        },
        success: {
          type: 'final'
        }
      }
    })).onTransition(state => {
      if (state.changed) {
        console.log('state ----> ', state.value);
      }
    })
     .onDone(() => { console.log('done--->'); return resolve()})
     .onStop(() => reject());
     .start();
   }
  });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add `async` to your function, then test it again.

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    return ...
}
```

Comment: I think you need to add `await` for any async function call. I mean `initiate`